# Odoo 10 : Catch the UserError and show it to webpage

Tags: python, error-handling, controller, odoo, html

I have a controller which calls the **action_approve** function in models.py and in the ends returns a webpage :

```
class Holiday(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/Approve', auth='public',type='http', methods=['GET'], website=True)
    def index(self,resid):

        record = http.request.env['hr.holidays'].search([('id', '=', resid)])
        print str(record)
        result=record.action_approve()
        return http.request.render('holiday.approve_page')
```

This is the **action_approve** function which has **UserError** statements :

```
@api.multi
    def action_approve(self):
        # if double_validation: this method is the first approval approval
        # if not double_validation: this method calls action_validate() below
        print "holiday calleds"
        if not self.env.user.has_group('hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_manager'):
            raise UserError(_('Only Leads can approve leave requests.'))
            return False
        manager = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.uid)], limit=1)

        notification=Notification()
        notification.notifyEmployee(self,'Approved')

        for holiday in self:
            if holiday.state != 'confirm':
                raise UserError(_('Leave request must be confirmed ("To Approve") in order to approve it.'))
                return False
            if holiday.double_validation:
                return holiday.write({'state': 'validate1', 'manager_id': manager.id if manager else False})
            else:
                holiday.action_validate()
```

I want to catch this **UserError** msgs and show them on the webpage to the user. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

this code worked:

```
try:
            record.action_approve()

except UserError,e:
            return http.request.render('holiday.approve_page', {'errorMsg': e[0]})
```